# get http request executing before put request although I used async await

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await, httprequest

I am trying to execute the put request before the get request, by using async and await, but the put executes after the get,
Can someone help please. Here is my code:

```
export class DataStorageService {
    constructor(private dataservice: DataServiceService, private http: HttpClient) {}
    storeData() {
        const movies = this.dataservice.Movies;
        this.http.put('https://my-movies-1f9a9.firebaseio.com/movies.json', movies).subscribe(
            responseData => {
                console.log(responseData);
                return responseData;
            }
        )
    }

    fetchData() {
        let movies: IMovie[];
        this.http.get < IMovie[] > ('https://my-movies-1f9a9.firebaseio.com/movies.json').subscribe(
            responseData => {
                movies = responseData;
                console.log(movies);
            }
        )
    }

    async asyncCall() {
        await this.datastorageservice.storeData();
        this.datastorageservice.fetchData();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `subscribe` is not necessary here as you want to use `async` and `await` keywords:

```
export class DataStorageService {
    constructor(private dataservice:DataServiceService, private http:HttpClient) { }

    storeData(){
        const movies=this.dataservice.Movies;
        this.http.put('https://my-movies-1f9a9.firebaseio.com/movies.json', movies)
    }

    fetchData(){
        let movies:IMovie[];
        this.http.get<IMovie[]>('https://my-movies-1f9a9.firebaseio.com/movies.json')
    }
}
```

and then you can use `async` and `await`:

```
async  asyncCall() {
    let result = await this.datastorageservice.storeData();
    let anotherResult = this.datastorageservice.fetchData();
}
```

If your service return `Observable`, then you need to to call `toPromise()` method:

```
async  asyncCall() {
    let result = await this.datastorageservice.storeData().toPromise();
    let anotherResult = this.datastorageservice.fetchData().toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your time,  the requests must stay as subscribe, for other uses, but I got your idea.

Comment: @om-cloud I am glad that it helped to you! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your http request a promise, personally I separate http requests in a service for example:

file.service:

```
async getData(): Promise<any> {
    const url = 'http://myrestservice';
    This.http.get(url,{Headers, observe: 'response' }).pipe(map((resp: any) => {
      return resp;
    })).toPromise();
  }
```

file.component:

```
const request: any = await this.requestServ.getData().then((resp) => resp).catch((err) => err);
```

I hope it is useful for you

Comment: Still trying to figure out your suggestion, thank you very much